# Error with a function pointer as a map parameter? C++

Tags: c++, function, pointers, dictionary

I seem to be getting several errors with

```
map<string,function<XMLSerializable*()>> mapConstructor;
```

Notably,

```
 la5.cpp: In function ‘int main(int, char**)’:
 la5.cpp:21:13: error: ‘function’ was not declared in this scope
 la5.cpp:21:43: error: ‘mapConstructor’ was not declared in this scope
 la5.cpp:21:43: error: template argument 2 is invalid
 la5.cpp:21:43: error: template argument 4 is invalid
 la5.cpp:25:58: warning: lambda expressions only available with -std=c++0x or - std=gnu++0x [enabled by default]
 la5.cpp:33:26: error: expected primary-expression before ‘*’ token
 la5.cpp:33:28: error: expected primary-expression before ‘)’ token
 la5.cpp:33:31: error: ‘pFunc’ was not declared in this scope
 make: *** [la5.o] Error 1
```

Unfortunately, I can't seem to find what I've done wrong, as it seems to deal with that map declaration which was given to the class by my instructor. Below is my .cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <functional>

#include "Armor.h"
#include "Weapon.h"
#include "Item.h"
#include "Creature.h"

using namespace std;

XMLSerializable * constructItem()
{
        return new Item;
}

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{

    map<string,function<XMLSerializable*()>> mapConstructor;

    mapConstructor["Item"] = constructItem;

    mapConstructor["Creature"] = []() {return new Creature; };

    cout << "Input the class name, then we'll try to construct it." << endl;

    string sLookup = " ";

    cin >> sLookup;

    function<XMLSerializable*()> pFunc = mapConstructor[sLookup];

    if(pFunc() == NULL)
    {
            cout << "Sorry, the object couldn't be constructed." << endl;
    }
    else
    {
            cout << pFunc() << " a non NULL value was returned!" << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Any suggestions? I'm unfamiliar with maps, but I believe this should work, right?

Coding in pico, compiling with a makefile using g++.

Comment: `std::function` isn't a function pointer, it's a wrapper class for all sorts of callables, including function pointers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you just are forgetting to add `-std=c++11` or `-std=c++0x` to your compiler flags to enable C++11.

`-std=c++0x` is deprecated, but on older versions of g++, `-std=c++11` is not available.

Comment: That's what I thought as well, but the prompt had only said to put the -std=c++0x in a certain spot, so I didn't question it. Trying with the c++0x standard everywhere compiled just fine, thanks!